# Picking fields from object with certain RecordType with Sanctuary

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, sanctuary

I have an object with options that corresponds to the following record type:

```js
const AwsRegionsEnum = $.EnumType(
  'AWS/Regions',
  'http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html',
  [
    'us-east-1',
    'us-east-2',
    'us-west-1',
    'us-west-2',
    'ca-central-1',
    'eu-west-1',
    'eu-central-1',
    'eu-west-2',
    'ap-northeast-1',
    'ap-northeast-2',
    'ap-southeast-1',
    'ap-southeast-2',
    'ap-south-1',
    'sa-east-1',
  ]
);
const Credentials = $.RecordType({
  accessKeyId: $.String,
  secretAccessKey: $.String,
  region: AwsRegionsEnum,
});

const PullOpts = $.RecordType({
  waitTimeSeconds: S.MaybeType($.Number),
  maxNumberOfMessages: S.MaybeType($.Number),
  credentials: Credentials,
});
```

And I want to create a function that picks options from such records like `R.pick` from ramda library. But I want to type list fields for picking. That list can contain only fields that are valid for record of type `PullOpts`.

Expected behavior for the function:

```
// pickOpts :: List(<some_type_for_validate_options>) -> PullOpts -> <constructed_type_for_return>
const pickOpts = (pickingOpts, allOpts) => {};
```

Summary:

1. How I can write type my function arguments correct
   (`<some_type_for_validate_options>` and
   `<constructed_type_for_return>`)?
2. How I can write body of the function using sanctuary function
   compositions?

Thanks for any help:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Sanctuary, it is usually not necessary to pick certain fields from a record. Consider this module:

```
const $ = require('sanctuary-def');
const types = require('./types');

const def = $.create({checkTypes: true, env: $.env});

//    User :: Type
const User = $.RecordType({
  id: types.UUID,
  username: $.NonEmpty($.String),
  email: types.Email,
});

//    MinimalUser :: Type
const MinimalUser = $.RecordType({
  id: types.UUID,
  username: $.NonEmpty($.String),
});

//    toMinimalUser :: User -> MinimalUser
const toMinimalUser = def(
  'toMinimalUser',
  {},
  [User, MinimalUser],
  user => ???
);
```

What is the implementation that should appear in place of the `???`. The answer may be surprising: we simply return `user`. This is because every member of the `User` type is also a member of the `MinimalUser` type. A record is permitted to contain additional fields. This makes it possible to define functions with types such as `id :: { id :: UUID } -> UUID` which are not restricted to a particular type (`User`, `Invoice`, or whatever).

So, `toMinimalUser` may be unnecessary. Since every member of the `User` type is also a member of the `MinimalUser` type, we can pass a `User`/`MinimalUser` to a function which expects a `MinimalUser`.

Although the type system won't require us to “strip” fields, we may wish to do so for privacy reasons. Consider `toJson :: User -> String`. If we're constructing an API response from a `User` value we may which to exclude the `email` field for privacy reasons. In this case I would suggest this implementation:

```
//    toJson :: User -> String
const toJson = def(
  'toJson',
  {},
  [User, $.String],
  ({id, username}) => JSON.stringify({id, username})
);
```

This is more verbose than the `R.pick` equivalent, but that's a price we must pay to deal with records in a more disciplined manner than is required by JavaScript.

I can imagine us one day adding a function such as this to Sanctuary:

```
S.pick :: Set String -> StrMap a -> StrMap a
```

I can't imagine, though, a similar function operating on arbitrary records as we'd be forced to use a loose type such as `Set String -> Object -> Object`. When dealing with records in Sanctuary I prefer to write code which is slightly more verbose but provides stronger guarantees.